# Problem formulation model

Tags: general-topology, machine-learning

I have to define a problem formulation for a classification supervised task in machine learning. In input I have 15 predictors $$ X= {x1,...x2} $$ and the output Y can take 2 values $$ Y = (Label1 , Label2) = (0,1) $$. Is it correct to say the model f that I am looking for is:
$$
f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightharpoonup\left\{ Label1,Label2\right\}
$$

Or as I have 15 inputs, `R` should have a shape to reflect input data and the formulation should be:
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^{15} \rightharpoonup\left\{ Label1,Label2\right\}
$$

Comment: As you ask here in math, I can only advice to state things mathematically correct, using usual notation. For example use $Y = \{Label1,Label2\}$ to express that $Y$ is a set(if it is one). Also I would use $\to$ as the arrow to indicate between which sets your maps map. As to your last question, you should choose the notation which reflects your model. If your predictors can be modeled as a 15-tuple of real numbers then $\mathbb{R}^{15}$ seems to be a good choice. Also I would use \colon, e.g. $f\colon$, for the double point, which is often the standard but of course also up to taste.

Answer (score 0):

Your domain should describe the number of predictor.

Assuming your predictors are real number, it should be $\mathbb{R}^{15}$.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Is it correct to say my model is from R^15 to a discrete space which is {Label 1, Label 2} or should I say from R^15 to unit space [0,1] ?

Comment: How does $f$ behaves, is it a probability value, or it only takes two possible value?

Comment: The output is a categorical, so: Label 1 is coded 0 and Label 2 is coded 1 at the exit of the neural network.

Comment: Then you can specify it to be $\{$ Label $1$, Label $2\}$

Comment: Label1 and Label are categorical element. For example Label1 and Label2 can be pathogenic and benign.

Comment: Ya, those are alright